# object reference = string reference; change to one doesn't affect the other?

Tags: c#

```
string name = "bob";
object obj = name; 
obj = "joe";
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

I'm a bit confused on how name will print bob. If string and object are both reference types, shouldn't they point to the same piece of memory on the heap after the "obj = name" assignment? Thanks for any clarification.

Edit: StackUnderflow's example brought up another related question.

```
MyClass myClass1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myClass2;
myClass1.value = 4;
myClass2 = myClass1;
myClass2.value = 5;  // myClass1 and myClass2 both have 5 for value
```

What happens when both are class references? Why does it not work the same way, as I can 
change a class field via one reference and it is reflected in the other. Class variables should also be references. Is that where stings being immutable comes into play?

Comment: Do you have a C++ background?

Comment: I did a long time ago.  I guess that's where I was getting confused?

Comment: @user943870 Probably - a lot of C++ people see "reference" and think "reference type" means something like a C++ reference, but it's very different.

Comment: I started with c++ and only used that.  I'll wrap my head around this eventually.

Comment: Please see "[Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208)".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> shouldn't they point to the same piece of memory on the heap after the "obj = name" assignment

Yes.  They both reference the same string instance.  You can see this by calling:

```
bool sameStringReference = object.ReferenceEquals(obj, name); // Will be true
```

However, as soon as you do:

```
obj = "joe";
```

You're changing this so that `obj` is now referencing a different string.  `name` will still be referencing the original string, however, as you haven't reassigned it.

If you then do:

```
sameStringReference = object.ReferenceEquals(obj, name); // Will be false
```

This will be false at this point.

Answer (score 5):

(Since the OP stated C++ background):

References in C# are not the same as references in C++, they act a bit more like pointers. In C#, they are not "bound" at initialization, so the assignment operator (`=`) **will assign a new reference instead of modifying the original object**.

In C++:

```
std::string name = "bob";
std::string& obj = name; // now bound to 'name'
obj = "joe"; // name is directly affected
std::cout << name; // prints "joe"
```

In C#:

```
string name = "bob";
string obj = name; // both reference "bob"
obj = "joe"; // obj now references "joe", and name still references "bob"
Console.WriteLine(name); // prints "bob"
```

Comment: Very nice example to illustrate the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you're simply reassigning the `obj` reference to a "joe" string object.  Strings are immutable so they can't be changed that way.  Best you can do is wrap `name` with your own class.

```
public class MyName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

MyName firstName = new MyName() { Name = "bob" };
MyName secondName = name;
secondName.Name = "joe";
Console.WriteLine(firstName.Name) //outputs "joe"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between assignment and acting on a variable. If you had this instead:

```
public class A { public string Name; }

...
var orig = new A { Name = "bob" };
var obj = orig;
obj.Name = "joe";
Console.WriteLine(orig.Name); //"joe"
```

Here you would be modifying the object that `obj` points to (instead of modifying what `obj` points to).